# how to make images redrawn on imageView inside ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView that is like an inbox. The information  comes from a user,so the ListView displays text and a userPicture.To display userPictures, I display the userPicture if exists or a imageView of a letter of the first name.

when I receive data from WS I launch an asynctask that compare userPicture ids with DB to ask the WS for ones I don't have or one's that have changed.

After the asyncTask finishes I save pictures locally and notify listView that the data set has changed, in order to look for the new pictures.

my problem comes when there is only 1 user on the listview and the picture wasn't found but was downloaded from WS. after calling notifyDataSetChanged, also calling refreshDrawableState and invalidateViews,that acording to  [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#invalidateViews%28%29) "Causes all the views to be rebuilt and redrawn". the image is not changed and imageView still shows the letter ImageView, 
neither scrolling through the listView its updated. (I guess is part of the Viewholder that recycle the views that is meant for performance and a good practive acording to ).

on the getView of the adapter I have a the Following statement to processThe Picture

```
if(mIDataPersistence.userHasPicture(userId)
ViewHolder.userImg.setImageBitmap(mIDataPersistence.getUserPicture(userId));
else
ViewHolder.userImg.setImageBitmap(BitmapUtils.createBitMap(userName);
```

note: mIDataPersistence is  persistence data interface to access all the data locally stored that I'm using here. and BitmapUtils.createBitMap() makes a bitmap from the first letter of the user.

can anyone help me or point me on a way to make listView update images in this particular case.

Comment: Why not call notifyDataSetChanged() on the Adapter to have it handle refreshing of the Views to be displayed?

Comment: I called it but is not working as espected